# heroku git repo change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

```
Muhammed-Bhikhas-MacBook-Pro:mashs_wing_ranch BH1KH4$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:sleepy-cliffs-9120.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:sleepy-cliffs-9120.git (push)
origin  git@heroku.com:gentle-bastion-5131.git (fetch)
origin  git@heroku.com:gentle-bastion-5131.git (push)
```

When I run git remote -v, I get the wrong app for heroku. That is an app I had previously, how do I get the `sleepy-cliffs-9120.git` to change to my new app `gentle-bastion-5131` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:gentle-bastion-5131.git
```

Comment: The url should be "git@heroku.com:gentle-bastion-5131.git", not just the end.